# HEAD~ for a merge commit

Tags: git

In Git, you can refer to the commit before HEAD using the shorthand HEAD~, and two before using HEAD~2, etc.

I have a repository that has a merge commit like the following:

```
A----B-------------F
      \           /
       C----D----E
```

HEAD = F, HEAD~ points to B, and HEAD~2 points to A. With a merge commit like this, is there a shorthand that would point to E?

Comment: You can checkout to the CDE branch and the HEAD~2 changes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes; the `~` specifies the generation, [but you can use `^` to specify the parent number](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection), in the case of a merge.

```
git show HEAD^2
```

Will show the 2nd parent.

(The distinction is especially subtle since without a numeric argument both `~` and `^` show the same thing, the first parent of `HEAD`.  This is because both `~` and `^` default to `1` without a numeric parameter.  So they show the first parent (by depth) and the first parent (by breadth) which are of course the same.)

Comment: oh for some reason I thought ^ and ~ were just two ways to do the same thing.

Comment: @Dismissile you are not alone, I thought the same :)

Comment: Right, it's not super obvious since often you simply want to see the immediate parent!  :)

Answer (score 3):

I know you asked for commit E, but the shorthand for commit C is an even better example for understanding the difference between ^ and ~.

Here is the shorthand for C:

```
HEAD^2~2
```

e.g. 2nd parent of HEAD and then 2 jumps down the first-parent chain from there.

Try cloning this repo to see for yourself (look for the "clone" link):

http://vm.bit-booster.com/bitbucket/plugins/servlet/bb_net/projects/BB/repos/a/commits

[image]

And here's how the various shorthands covered in this answer resolve:

```
git show --no-patch --oneline HEAD
1286a9a F

git show --no-patch --oneline HEAD^2
9640db6 E

git show --no-patch --oneline HEAD^2~2
506916b C
```

Exercise for the reader:  what's another way (using this repo) to write HEAD^2~3?

Comment: The answer:  HEAD^2~3 in this example is identical to HEAD~1  :-)